# How do you set the contents of a dynamically allocated array?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization, declaration

i am a bit confusing about how to assign global pointer and giving value in main 
function??

for example, here my code example

```
bool *list;
int main()
{
  list=new bool[7];    
  //i want to auto add a value but how, is that below code is correct??
  list={true,false,true,true,true,true};
}
```

i try with bloodshed c++
sorry for my bad English.

Comment: you have to do it manually; assign value to each index and also donot forget to delete the memory you have dynamically allocated...

Answer (score 2):

This syntax

```
list={true,false,true,true,true,true};
```

is wrong.

Instead you could write

```
bool *list;
int main()
{
  list=new bool[7] {true,false,true,true,true,true};    
}
```

Or you should use the assignment operator

```
bool *list;
int main()
{
  list=new bool[7];
  list[0] = true;
  list[1] = false;
  list[2] = true;
  list[3] = true;
  list[4] = true;
  list[5] = true;     
}
```

Or you could use a pointer to an object of type std::array. For example

```
#include <array>

std::array<bool, 7> *list;

int main()
{
  list=new std::array<bool, 7>;

  *list =  {true,false,true,true,true,true};    
}
```

And at last you could use `std::vector<bool>` instead of the pointer. or `std::bitset`:)

Comment: :list=new bool[7] {true,false,true,true,true,true}; will not work.

Comment: @Sumeet, It's fine in C++11.

Comment: @Sumee It depends on what compiler you are using.  The new C++ Standard was adopted more than two years ago.:)

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: I got it.

Comment: @Sumeet As far as I know the C++ 2014 also was adopted not so far.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow, We're all hoping for a final no problems meeting and end of Summer success. If any final conflicts arise, I believe it will be closer to the end of the year.

Answer (score 0):

```
list[0] = true;
list[1] = false;
list[2] = true;
list[3] = true;
list[4] = true;
list[5] = true;
list[6] = ???; (whatever you want it to be - true or false)
```

That is the easiest way, when you don't have tens or hundreds of elements.

Comment: so there no other way instead of assign it one by one??

Comment: If C++11 is available, even easier: `list = new bool[7]{true, false, ..., true};`. If not, an option is a temporary array and `std::copy_n`. Of course it should be a `std::vector`, though (one thing to note is that it accepts `v = {...};`).

Comment: yes chris..
what you mention is working fine when using linux with gcc compiler..
the issue coming when i switch my OS to windows and use bloodshed c++ as compiler, do you know how to update c++ version to c++11 in bloodshed c++

Comment: @plutoIsNotPlanet, I'm assuming you're still using GCC. Just install a newer version of GCC and update the settings in Dev accordingly. Or tell Dev to use C++11 if it can with your current version and isn't. Also, I said `std::vector` and forgot you had `bool`s. That's not a particularly nice combination. In all honestly, that might work for your purposes, and `std::deque` is a decent alternative.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a bitset instead of an array.

```
#include <bitset>
#include <string>

std::bitset<7>* list;

int main()
{
    list = new std::bitset<7>;

    *list = std::bitset<7>(std::string("111101"));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the pointer and the dynamic allocation? Why not simply:

```
bool list[7] = {true,false,true,true,true,true};

int main()
{
    // ... no need to initialize or assign here ...
}
```

Note: The array is of size 7, but you only provide 6 initial values. Are you sure that is what you want?

Comment: i think u're correct, but
is that possible to change one array inside main function??
like bellow:

int main()
{
  list[1]=true;
}

Comment: Sure it's possible. Do you want to prevent that? Then put a `const` before the `bool list[7] = ...` part.

Comment: in linux using g++ it's working, but in windows what your mention not working, maybe it's because c++11 is not compatible with my bloodshed dev c++.. any way thank's for your help..

Comment: There is nothing C++11 specific in my code. There must be some silly mistake in your code. Can you paste it [on ideone](https://ideone.com) and post a link?